# RadioButtonList Textbox nested... C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to input a text box control inside a RadioButtonList control in C#.  Below is the way I have been doing it, but I have been trying to gather the values in the textboxes and it always passes null value even when data is in the textbox.  Any ideas or suggestions?

--aspx

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblContactMethod" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblContactMethod_OnSelectedIndexChanged" GroupName="grpContactMethod" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="All" Text="All">All</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Range">Range: <input name="txtDateRange1" id="txtDateRange1" type="text" /> to <input name="txtDateRange2" id="txtDateRange2" type="text" /></asp:ListItem>         
        <asp:ListItem Value="Single" Text="SingleDate">Single Date: <input id="txtSingleDate" type="text" /></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

-- aspx.cs
I even tried this:

```
  TextBox txt1 = FindControl("txtDateRange1") as TextBox;
  TextBox txt2 = FindControl("txtDateRange2") as TextBox;
```

Comment: Try adding runat="server" to your textboxes

Comment: Now I am getting... Parser Error Message: The 'Text' property of 'asp:ListItem' does not allow child objects. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs are not aspx controls and they are not having attribute runat="server". This means you cannot reach them on backend. You need to either make them accesible, or get the value after postback like:

```
Request.Form["txtDateRange1"]
```